# Forms authentication on different hostings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms

Hi have form authenticaion for my site, and it works fine on localhost and godaddy, but after moving to another hosting it stop working. 
After login in admin area after 2-3 minutes I redirecting back to login screen. 
Does anybody know if I change some settings on IIS or what is the source of the problem?
My code looks like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>


FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application domain is being shut down and you have no machineKey section in Web.config (or validationKey/decryptionKey="AutoGenerate") you will get new validationKey/decriptionKey after every application start and authentication cookies will become invalid. Visit http://aspnetresources.com/tools/keycreator.aspx and add generated machineKey section into your Web.config.